# Postgres: JOIN with first non-null value that matches?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using Postgres 9.6. My database contains presentations, belonging to users. Each presentation has many slides. Each slide may optionally have a background image.

```
Table "public.presentation"
id             │ integer
user_id        │ integer

Table "public.slide"
id               | integer
presentation_id  | integer (foreign key)
index            | integer

Table "public.background"
slide_id .     | integer (foreign key)
image_id       │ integer
```

I would like to retrieve the list of presentations for a particular user, and along with the name and ID of each presentation, I would like to get the ID of the background image of the first slide that has a background image (or null if none of its slides has a background image). This is so I can present a thumbnail alongside each presentation.

Currently I have a query to get the background image ID of the first slide in the presentation only:

```
SELECT presentation.*, background.image_id 
FROM presentation 
JOIN -- get the first slide in each presentation
  (SELECT presentation_id FROM slide WHERE index=0) 
  ON slide.presentation_id=presentation.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN -- join this with background (even if null)
  background ON background.slide_id=slide.id
WHERE presentation.user_id=100
ORDER BY presentation.id;
```

But I'd like to change this to get the first non-null background image ID for each presentation. Not sure how to do this!

I'm wondering if Postgres's [`first_value`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/functions-window.html) can help me somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from
    presentation
    left join (
        select
            b.image_id, s.presentation_id as id,
            row_number() over (
                partition by s.presentation_id
                order by s.index
            ) as rn
        from
            slide s
            inner join
            background b on b.slide_id = s.id
    ) b using (id)
where rn = 1 or rn is null
```

Answer (score 0):

It *looks* like you only need two columns to get the information you're missing.

```
select slide.presentation_id, min(background.image_id) as background_image_id
from slide
left join background
    on slide.id = background.slide_id
group by slide.presentation_id
order by slide.presentation_id, background_image_id;
```

This gives you one row per presentation.

```
with first_background_image as (
    select slide.presentation_id, min(background.image_id) as background_image_id
    from slide
    left join background
        on slide.id = background.slide_id
    group by slide.presentation_id
), first_slide as (
    select presentation_id, min(index) as first_slide_id
    from slide
    group by presentation_id
)
select fs.presentation_id, fs.first_slide_id, fbi.background_image_id
from first_slide fs
left join first_background_image fbi
    on fbi.presentation_id = fs.presentation_id
order by presentation_id;
```

---

You should include CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements in your question.

```
create table presentation (
    id integer primary key,
    user_id integer not null
);

create table slide (
    id integer primary key,
    presentation_id integer not null 
        references presentation (id),
    index integer not null,
    unique (presentation_id, index)
);

create table background (
    -- Assumes one background per slide.
    slide_id integer primary key
        references slide (id),
    image_id integer not null
        -- references something?
);

insert into presentation values (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 2);
insert into slide values (1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (3, 1, 3), (4, 2, 1), (5, 2, 2), (6, 3, 1);
insert into background values (1, 3), (2, 7), (5, 18);
```